# Installed Magento 2.0.4 with composer, importet DB from Live-System, 404s are present

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0.4

We planned to create a stage of our Live System.

We are using Magento 2.0.4.

- I installed Magento 2.0.4 with Composer and installed Magento over
  the Web.
- I uploaded Themes and pub/media-Files to the desired
  destinations.
- I implemented splendid-Internets de_DE-CSV. I importet
  the DB with `mysql -Ddatabase < dump.sql` (worked nicely)
- corrected base_url in the core-row via PhpMyadmin
- I removed cache and pub/static/*
- I did `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy de_DE en_US`
- I switched to developer mode
- I also commented the Dev-Line in the roots .htaccess out
- Filesettings are correct (as stated in Magentos Documents)

However, we are receiving huge 404s on both frontend and backend.

Tried:

- change di.xml from `Symlink` to `Copy`
- set files to 777

Non of those have worked.

[image]

Our server settings:

- PHP 7.0
- Apache2 (rewrites enabled)

The files are present in `pub/static/...`, however, you can't access them from the browser directly. Filesettings for those files are 755 for Folders, and 644 for files. Should be fine - but won't work.

We are running out of ideas.

Comment: Please check for `.htaccess` & Base URL which needs to be change Go to `core_config_data` table & check web/unsecure/base_url, web/secure/base_url

Comment: Ah, forgot to mention that - of course I did that already.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to modify two files:

- vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/DriverInterface.php
- vendor/magento/module-deploy/Model/Filesystem.php

There are two lines that define which settings new files should have. I've changed it from `770`to `775` and from `660` to `664`. Now its working.

Comment: It will work until you do a composer update. Out of principal you should never edit anything in core files. I think your issue is that you have not set up your magento file owner correctly on your server, so files created by the command line are not accessible by the magento or www user, or you ran the commands using the wrong user.

Comment: The hosting env if set up to work perfectly file with owner settings (which has been verified multiple times by me and our hoster). However, of course, editing core files is not a good idea! Anyhow, "do an update" is not always the right answer to a question.

Comment: Well, somethings doesn't seem correct with your setup, else it would work ;). And "Do an update" wasn't the answer I gave you either. Did you check the file owner of your static content? Did you run the deployment command using the correct user? You can always issue the command using a different user than the one you are logged in as using something along these lines (if www-data is the correct user) `su www-data -s /bin/bash -c "bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy de_DE en_US"`. Gruss vom Bodensee.

Comment: Meanwhile, we sortet the problem out and found out, that our hoster has security settings enabled that has problems with --0 settings. Therefore, there were literally no other chance besides changing the core function. The user who's managing the server via SSH is the correct and authorized user, yes, and commands have issued like described above. We didn't tried to change the user because another user would have the same Privileges (so it doesn't matter). Didn't wanted to sound harsh - every input is helpful! :-) Gruß aus München!

Comment: Sidenote: on shared hosting you mostly can't issue the su or sudo command.

Comment: Glad to hear you sorted it. I didn't realise you were trying to run it on shared-hosting. And no harm done! =)